# How to store the context of users in HashMap?

Tags: rust

My program is processing commands from different users.  Each user has its own state that is modified by the commands he issues.

I use a HashMap to store the state of the users:

```
let mut states = HashMap::new();
```

A state is a struct:

```
pub struct State {
    // details omitted
}
```

The program looks like this:

```
// loop
        // current user is identified by 1st char of command
        current_user = command[0..1].to_string()

        match states.get(&current_user) {
            Some(&state) => {
                println!("Switching User...");
                current_state = state;
                }
            _ => {
                println!("Creating User...");
                current_state = State{...details omitted...};
                states.insert(current_user, current_state);
                }
            }
//     execute command in the State of the user
```

But I get the following error.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
42 |         match states.get(&current_user) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
43 |             Some(&state) => {
   |                   ----
   |                   |
   |                   data moved here
   |                   move occurs because `state` has type `Repository`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

See [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9f1ca050eec62d100f46bcbd9c6eabc).

How can the program be fixed ? Do I need to use another structure than a HashMap ?

Comment: Could you show how is used current_user in context ? And maybe show the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `states.entry(..).or_insert(..)` instead of `states.get()..`.

The code is actually simpler (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfecc3b08ff0b8ac197678cd5e4c5f54))

```
    current_state = states.entry(current_user)
         .or_insert(State{v: String::from("P")});
```